# Intersection between $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $\mathbb{C}P^1$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, projective-geometry, intersection-theory

I would like to compute the number of points in the intersection of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $\mathbb{C}P^1$ in $\mathbb{C}P^2$.
I choose $$\mathbb{R}P^2=\{ [x_0:y_0:z_0]\mid x_i\in\mathbb{R}\}$$ 
and $$\mathbb{C}P^2=\{[z_0:z_1:z_2]\mid  a_0 z_0+a_1z_1+a_2z_2=0\} $$
where $a_i\in\mathbb{C}$. So I need to compute the number of points satisying 
$a_0 x_0+a_1x_1 a_2x_2=0$  where $a_i\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$, but I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing some unstated aspect of how you intend to "count" these points, as I surely don't see how the solutions to $a_0 x_0+a_1x_1 a_2x_2=0$ constitute an "intersection". But are there not infinitely many such points?

Answer (score 1):

They intersect in a circle = $\mathbb{RP}^{1}$. Just choose the line $\mathbb{CP}^{1}  \subset \mathbb{CP}^{2}$, given by the equation  $\{z_{2}=0\}$ (corresponding to the choice $a_{0}=a_{1}=0, a_{2}=1$), then the real points satisfying this equation are of the form $[x_{0}:x_{1}:0]$, where $x_{1},x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ (not both zero).

This is a copy of 1-dimensional real projective space, which is diffeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: You know stating something without providing any justification is just meaningless.

Comment: Maybe my solution is a bit sketchy, I will add a few more details.